# selectmanylistbox error after upgrade jquery 1.8.3 to 1.12.3

Tags: jquery, upgrade, selectmanylistbox

When I upgrade jquery 1.8.3 to 1.12.3 version my previously worked
**selectmanylistbox** showing an error. After selecting one item from the list, the remove works but then the next time I am not able to select the same item from the list.
Before upgrade its working fine in version 1.8.3 jquery.